# How to set variable as categories in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a variable

```
 var country = ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'];
```

I want to set the categories of my chart into variable country. Please help.. 
I am new to Highcharts. Thanks

```
   var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'chart',
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Compliance Tracker '
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put it like this :

```
var country = ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'];
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: country,
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            }....
            ......
});
```

Here is the working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3gGYK/

I hope, you want to know the same.

Comment: Yes it is working.. Thanks. Is this the same with the series data?